# Apache Poi : Getting scientific notated double value in place of Numeric value

Tags: java, apache-poi

My actual number is : "89148000001958100000" (i.e) Excel column data,  After getting data through apahce poi plugin it is converting to 8.91480000019581E+019.

Convertion Code snippet :

**import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;**

**double dd = cell.getNumericCellValue();**

How can i achieve my actual number in excel file.

Please suggest...

Comment: I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77570180/3850730) and it might help.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();


String value= fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
```

You can display the value as it is in excel using [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)

You can also convert String into required format using BigDecimal or BigInteger classes to hold larger values

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution to converting Scientific notated number to normal number

The code snippet:

```
 NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");

 String opt = formatter.format(value);
```

This code gives actual number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigDecimal for this aswell. You can directly return a BigDecimal too or String representation of the large number.

Let's say the cell holds the big value

```
private String getStringValue(Cell cell)
    {
        if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.NUMERIC)
        {
            return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())).toPlainString();
        }
        else if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING)
        {
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        }

        return "";
    }
```